# Rollupjs doesn't bundle all files

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6, commonjs, rollupjs, lerna

I use rollup in my typescript project for bundling. When I use `"module": "commonjs"` in my tsconfig, the rollup output contains only insides of the file specified in the `input` in `rollup.config.js`. However, when I change tsconfig module to `esnext` or `es2015` everything seems to work fine. But I also use `lerna` monorepo so switching to different module messes up my imports from different packages. Is there a way to do something without switching module in order for rollup to work or maybe I should rewrite some code in a project? Thanks in advance!

Here's a part of my `rollup.config.js`:

```
import typescript from '@rollup/plugin-typescript';
import { nodeResolve } from '@rollup/plugin-node-resolve';
import commonjs from '@rollup/plugin-commonjs';

export default {
  input: {
    'src/index': 'src/index.ts',
    'src/tests': 'src/tests.ts',
  },
  external: ['chalk'],
  output: {
    dir: 'lib',
    format: 'cjs',
    freeze: false,
    interop: false,
    sourcemap: false,
    chunkFileNames: '[name].js',
  },

  plugins: [
    nodeResolve(),
    typescript(),
    commonjs({include: '../../node_modules/**})
  ],
};
```

Comment: Configure the `commonjs` plugin to also include your own source files?

Comment: @FelixKling well I thought typescript plugin should do it by itself cos that's what rollup is about. Adding source files to `commonjs` results in other problems such as duplicate functions on Windows and weird behavior on Linux and macOS

Comment: Well, rollup itself only understands ES modules. So if you tell typescript to produce CJS modules, then that's not going to work. Hence you using the `commonjs` plugin for external dependencies atm. I mean, if you can you should let typescript produce ES modules, but I'm not familiar with lerna and how that would need to be configured.

Answer (score 3):

Turns out, you shouldn’t try to use “module”: “CommonJS” for bundling. If you want to keep CommonJS output just specify “format”: “cjs” in your rollup config